# ImageJ - How to continue batch process even when encountered error

Tags: java, error-handling, batch-processing, imagej

I have written a macro in ImageJ to run batch "Measurements" on a list of BMP image files. I am running the code on a remote linux machine in headless mode using headless.jar.

Whenever ImageJ encounters an error or exception while reading/loading an image in the list, it exits the process. Hence, I have to constantly monitor the process and manually force ImageJ to skip the file.

Is there a way I can force ImageJ to continue with the process even though it encountered an error/exception? and report the filename maybe in the logs or another file?

Comment: It sounds like you should consider rewriting your macro as a Java Plugin. That would give you the option of performing the error handling you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to explicitly handle exceptions in the ImageJ macro language. However, you can guard against certain types of exceptions by checking preconditions and such before making a problematic macro call.

For example, if your list of files includes nonexistent ones, you can use `File.exists(path)` [[1]](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#File.exists) to ensure the file exists before you attempt to open it.

Of course, not all error conditions can be easily checked this way (e.g., malformed BMPs), so I agree with [medPhys-pl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1128171/medphys-pl) that rewriting your macro as an Imagej plugin is the most complete solution. You can get a good start using the Macro Recorder (`Plugins > Macros > Record`) set to record in Plugin mode rather than Macro. Once you have the relevant commands to execute, you can package them into a plugin easily by using [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/)'s [Script Editor](http://fiji.sc/Using_the_Script_Editor):

1. `File > New > Script`
2. `Language > Java`
3. `Templates > Java > Bare PlugIn`
4. Paste your commands into the `run` method.

See the Fiji wiki's [Introduction into Developing Plugins](http://fiji.sc/Introduction_into_Developing_Plugins) for more details on writing ImageJ plugins.